# RadioButton Command property not working with xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, radio-button, nuget-update

RadioButton command property not working after updated from Xamarin.Forms 4.7 to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2337. what are the alternative ways to use command in ViewModel not with codebehind.

Comment: this might help. https://pauldboer.medium.com/xamarin-forms-radiobutton-list-source-binding-using-reactiveui-c76ac508

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,since Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0, the property `Command` has been removed from RadioButton.

If you want to run a command upon state change then you can use the event [CheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton#respond-to-radiobutton-state-changes).

```
    <RadioButton Content="test">
        <RadioButton.Behaviors>
            <local:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page}, Path=BindingContext.RadioCommand}"   CommandParameter="V"/>
        </RadioButton.Behaviors>
    </RadioButton>
```

For `EventToCommandBehavior.cs`, you can refer sample code here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors .

Note:

`Page` is the `x:Name` of current page.